# in VB Trying to create an Array of Properties

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

I'm trying to Create an Array of Properties. To simplify my problem I created a mini project

Project: I have 3 shapes, which change color and number when I press the button.
I have created a class for each set of properties.

```
Public Class Shape
  Dim _color As Color

End Class
```

Adding in a couple of objects for testing (coding colors first)

```
 Public Shared Sub Main()

    Dim ShapeList As New List(Of Shape)
    ShapeList .Add(New Shape() With {_color = Color.Blue})
    ShapeList .Add(New Shape() With {_color = Color.Green})
    ShapeList .Add(New Shape() With {_color = Color.Red})

    Display()
  End Sub
```

When the button is pressed I wish to display a sorted/random set from an array of objects

```
Public Sub Display(ByVal ShapeList As Object)

    Dim ScreenObject As Array
    ScreenObject(0) With {.OvalShape1}  'This is where I am stuck
    ScreenObject(1) =  .OvalShape2      'How to create this property in the
                                        'ScreenObject array?

        For Each obj As Shape In ShapeList
        ScreenObject(0).Color = ShapeList(0).Color
End Sub
```

Clarification: The three shapes are OvalShape1, 2 and 3 respectively. But for the little skills I have in VB, I struggle to find the answer.

Comment: do you want to create an ScreenObject array, and to add OvalShapes to it?

Comment: OvalShapes are Design elements, I'd like an array Screen Object to store the Ovalshape1,2 and 3 as property titles? not sure what you call them.
So when ScreenObject(0).Color is in actual fact OvalShape1.Color

Comment: use List(of t) instead of Arrays